# java.util.NoSuchElementException error( maybe because of Scanner)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting 'RunTime Error' java.util.NoSuchElementException in the line where I tried getting the user input. Don't know how to get rid of it.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        double amount = sc.nextDouble();
        if(input%5!=0){
            System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", amount));
        }else if(input>amount){
            System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", amount));
        }else{
            double bankAmount = 0.50;
            double ans = amount - (double)input;
            System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",ans-bankAmount));
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

The complete error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Codechef.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: I don't know why you say 'maybe'. The stack trace confirms it. Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: Can you share your inputs? This exception genrally occurs when there is no Integer element to be read from your stream.

Comment: please provide your sample inputs, as i have ran this code it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: 30 120.00 , 42 120.00 inputs @BlackPearl

Comment: @immukul Seems to work for me for the same inputs.

Comment: @BlackPearl The logic in the code works fine, but when I run it on CodeChef IDE it gives me the above error.

Comment: You are probably not passing your custom inputs correctly. Please recheck the way you pass custom inputs in the IDE. Please note that custom inputs in Codechef are passed before the program is executed.

Comment: @BlackPearl it worked while submitting, giving the error only while running. I tried a different approach and same error while running, though it says 'correct answer' after submitting.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
    {        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer value:");
            if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int input = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter double value:");
                if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    double amount = sc.nextDouble();
                    if(input%5!=0 ||input>amount){
                        System.out.println("amount="+String.format("%.2f", amount));
                    }else{
                        double bankAmount = 0.50;
                        double ans = amount - (double)input;
                        System.out.println("ans="+String.format("%.2f",ans-bankAmount));
                    }
                }            
        }     
       System.out.println("Program exited on invalid value!");
        sc.close();
    }
```